# Converting yuv 4:2:0 file to Rgb not getting expected output

Tags: c++, c++11, image-processing, video-processing, file-handling

The logic I am using is that I am reading he yuv file in a buffer and using 3 pointers to point to the Y,U,V components. The image dimension is 1920*1080.

I am

- taking 4 y pixels for corresponding 1U,1V pixels.
- Extracting the pixel value in integers.
- Converting the Y,U,V to R,G,B and storing the components in RGB buffer.

But the video output is incorrect. The output is somewhat like black and white

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char* g_pcRGBbuffer;
unsigned char* g_pcYUVBuffer;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int l_nSize = 1920 * 1080 * 1.5;

    g_pcYUVBuffer = new unsigned char[l_nSize];
    g_pcRGBbuffer = new unsigned char[1920 * 1080 * 3];
    FILE* fp_source;
    FILE* fp_rgb = NULL;
    int l_nY, l_nU, l_nV;
    double l_dR, l_dG, l_dB, l_ni;

    fp_source = fopen("D:\\Sample_1920x1080.yuv", "rb");
    // converting yuv file to rgb file
    if (fp_source)
    {
        fp_rgb = fopen("D:\\Sample_1920x1080.rgb", "wb+");
        while (!feof(fp_source))
        {
            fread(g_pcYUVBuffer, 1, l_nSize, fp_source);
            unsigned char* l_pcY = g_pcYUVBuffer;
            unsigned char* l_pcU = l_pcY + 1920 * 1080;
            unsigned char* l_pcV = l_pcU + ((1920 * 1080) / 4);
            unsigned char* l_pcRGBbuffer = g_pcRGBbuffer;

            for (l_ni = 0; l_ni < (1920 * 1080) / 4; l_ni++)
            {
                l_nY = l_pcY[0];
                l_nU = l_pcU[0];
                l_nV = l_pcV[0];

                l_dR = l_nY + 1.402 * (l_nV - 128);
                l_dG = l_nY - 0.34414 * (l_nU - 128) - 0.71414 * (l_nV - 128);
                l_dB = l_nY + 1.772 * (l_nU - 128);

                // This prevents colour distortions in  rgb image
                if (l_dR < 0)
                    l_dR = 0;
                else if (l_dR > 255)
                    l_dR = 255;
                if (l_dG < 0)
                    l_dG = 0;
                else if (l_dG > 255)
                    l_dG = 255;
                if (l_dB < 0)
                    l_dB = 0;
                else if (l_dB > 255)
                    l_dB = 255;

                // 1st pixel of RGB
                l_pcRGBbuffer[0] = l_dR;
                l_pcRGBbuffer[1] = l_dG;
                l_pcRGBbuffer[2] = l_dB;

                l_nY = l_pcY[1];
                l_nU = l_pcU[0];
                l_nV = l_pcV[0];

                l_dR = l_nY + 1.402 * (l_nV - 128);
                l_dG = l_nY - 0.34414 * (l_nU - 128) - 0.71414 * (l_nV - 128);
                l_dB = l_nY + 1.772 * (l_nU - 128);

                if (l_dR < 0)
                    l_dR = 0;
                else if (l_dR > 255)
                    l_dR = 255;
                if (l_dG < 0)
                    l_dG = 0;
                else if (l_dG > 255)
                    l_dG = 255;
                if (l_dB < 0)
                    l_dB = 0;
                else if (l_dB > 255)
                    l_dB = 255;

                // 2nd pixel of RGB
                l_pcRGBbuffer[3] = l_dR;
                l_pcRGBbuffer[4] = l_dG;
                l_pcRGBbuffer[5] = l_dB;

                l_nY = l_pcY[2];
                l_nU = l_pcU[0];
                l_nV = l_pcV[0];

                l_dR = l_nY + 1.402 * (l_nV - 128);
                l_dG = l_nY - 0.34414 * (l_nU - 128) - 0.71414 * (l_nV - 128);
                l_dB = l_nY + 1.772 * (l_nU - 128);

                if (l_dR < 0)
                    l_dR = 0;
                else if (l_dR > 255)
                    l_dR = 255;
                if (l_dG < 0)
                    l_dG = 0;
                else if (l_dG > 255)
                    l_dG = 255;
                if (l_dB < 0)
                    l_dB = 0;
                else if (l_dB > 255)
                    l_dB = 255;

                // 3rd pixel of RGB
                l_pcRGBbuffer[6] = l_dR;
                l_pcRGBbuffer[7] = l_dG;
                l_pcRGBbuffer[8] = l_dB;

                l_nY = l_pcY[3];
                l_nU = l_pcU[0];
                l_nV = l_pcV[0];

                // l_dR = 1.164*(l_nY-16 ) + 1.596*(l_nV-128 );
                // l_dG = 1.164*(l_nY-16 ) - 0.813*(l_nV-128 ) - 0.391*(l_nU-128);
                // l_dB = 1.164*(l_nY-16 ) + 2.018*(l_nU-128 );

                l_dR = l_nY + 1.402 * (l_nV - 128);
                l_dG = l_nY - 0.34414 * (l_nU - 128) - 0.71414 * (l_nV - 128);
                l_dB = l_nY + 1.772 * (l_nU - 128);

                if (l_dR < 0)
                    l_dR = 0;
                else if (l_dR > 255)
                    l_dR = 255;
                if (l_dG < 0)
                    l_dG = 0;
                else if (l_dG > 255)
                    l_dG = 255;
                if (l_dB < 0)
                    l_dB = 0;
                else if (l_dB > 255)
                    l_dB = 255;

                // 4th pixel of RGB
                l_pcRGBbuffer[9] = l_dR;
                l_pcRGBbuffer[10] = l_dG;
                l_pcRGBbuffer[11] = l_dB;

                l_pcY += 4;
                l_pcU += 1;
                l_pcV += 1;
                l_pcRGBbuffer += 12;
            }

            fwrite(g_pcRGBbuffer, 1, 1920 * 1080 * 3, fp_rgb);
        }

        printf("Video converted to rgb file \n ");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("fail\n");
    }

    fclose(fp_rgb);
    fclose(fp_source);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Rather than repeating all that formula and all the clamping to the range 0..255 three times, consider writing that as a function so you have less to correct and maintain. Also, rather than saying `if(fopen...)` and indenting and then `if(open...)` and indenting again, IMHO it makes code less indented and easier to read if you just return out of the function immediately as soon as you know something has gone wrong, i.e. `if(!fopen...){...; return}`

Comment: Have you checked the layout of your YUV file, or are you guessing it is arranged in groups of 4? Often all the Y values come first, then the subsampled U then the V values...

Comment: my yuv file is 4:2:0 planar format so  i assumed there would be four 4y pixels for every 1U and 1V.since the number of y pixels is 4times that of u and v.am i pointing at the correct location for l_pcY,l_pcU,l_pcV??

Comment: If it's planar, all the Y pixels come first, then all the U pixels then all the V pixels. Would you care to share your file?

Comment: Hi, OP. I've run your code through an auto-formatter and fixed the formatting in the post so all code is displayed as code. I've also fixed your grammar and added the c++ tag. People are less likely to see your post if you only tag it with c++11. If you tag a post with c++11, you should usually also tag it with c++.

Comment: thanks for the help everyone i fixed the problem i was taking the Y,U,V pixels incorrectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually YUV 4:2:0 planar stores all Y pixels first,then U pixels,then V pixels
To extract correct pixels use the following forumla:

```
//Refer wikipedia for further details
size.total = size.width * size.height;
 y = yuv[position.y * size.width + position.x];
 u = yuv[(position.y / 2) * (size.width / 2) + (position.x / 2) + size.total];
 v = yuv[(position.y / 2) * (size.width / 2) + (position.x / 2) + size.total +           (size.total / 4)];
```

YUV2RGBTestApp2.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char *g_pcRGBbuffer;
unsigned char *g_pcYUVBuffer;

int  _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int l_nSize = 1920 * 1080 * 1.5;
    g_pcYUVBuffer = new unsigned char[l_nSize];
    g_pcRGBbuffer = new unsigned char[1920 * 1080 * 3];
    FILE *fp_source;
    FILE *fp_rgb = NULL;
    int l_ny, l_nu, l_nv, l_ni, RGBval;
    int l_dr, l_dg, l_db;
    fp_source = fopen("D:\\Sample_1920x1080.yuv", "rb");
    int l_nj;


//converting yuv file to rgb file
     if (fp_source) {
          fp_rgb = fopen("D:\\Sample_1920x1080.rgb", "wb");
          while (!feof(fp_source))
            {
                fread(g_pcYUVBuffer, 1, l_nSize, fp_source);
                unsigned char *l_pcRGBbuffer = g_pcRGBbuffer;
                for (int j = 0; j < 1080; j++)
                {
                   for (int i = 0; i<1920; i++)
                    {
                   /*
                          Position  for y,u,v components for yuv planar 4:2:0  
                          Refer wikipedia for further reference  
                            
                   */
                      int Y = g_pcYUVBuffer[j * 1920 + i];
                      int U = g_pcYUVBuffer[((j / 2) * 960) + (i / 2) + (1920 * 1080)];
                      int V = g_pcYUVBuffer[((j / 2) * 960) + (i / 2) + (1920 * 1080) + ((1920 * 1080) / 4)];

                       int R = 1.164*(Y - 16) + 1.596*(V - 128);
                       int G = 1.164*(Y - 16) - 0.813*(V - 128) - 0.391*(U - 128);
                       int B = 1.164*(Y - 16) + 2.018*(U - 128);



                       if (R>255)R = 255;
                       if (R<0)R = 0;
                       if (G>255)G = 255;
                       if (G<0)G = 0;
                       if (B>255)B = 255;
                       if (B<0)B = 0;


                       l_pcRGBbuffer[0] = R;
                       l_pcRGBbuffer[1] = G;
                       l_pcRGBbuffer[2] = B;
                       l_pcRGBbuffer += 3;

                }
             }
        
            fwrite(g_pcRGBbuffer, 1, 1920 * 1080 * 3, fp_rgb);
        }

        printf("Video converted to rgb file \n ");

     }
     else {
        printf("fail\n");
   }

    fclose(fp_rgb);
    fclose(fp_source);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well done! Thank you for sharing back with the community. You can *"accept"* your own answer and grab the points too.